# independent prototyping with java

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am new to java (well I played with it a few times), and I am wondering:

=> How to do *fast* independent prototypes ? something like one file projects.

The last few years, I worked with python. Each time I had to develop some new functionality or algorithm, I would make a simple python module (i.e. file) just for it. I could then integrate all or part of it into my projects. So, how should I translate such "modular-development" workflow into a java context?

Now I am working on some relatively complex java DB+web project using spring, maven and intelliJ. And I can't see how to easily develop and run independent code into this context.

**Edit:**

I think my question is unclear because I confused two things:

1. fast developement and test of code snippets
2. incremental development

In my experience (with python, no web), I could pass from the first to the second seemlessly.

For the sake of consistency with the title, **the 1st has priority**. However it is good only for exploration purpose. In practice, the 2nd is more important.

Comment: What do you want to do with the results of these "projects"?  Are they really just components of a larger project?  If so, TDD might be your answer.

Comment: Springs dependency injection lets you isolate modules for testing by allowing you to mock injected objects

Comment: My question is quite vague, something like "what is the equivalent working method". I am simply used to working with the dynamic language  that is python. TDD seems a good idea, I should look into it.

Comment: Do you want to write a small one-off program? The answer is to use a different language: that is not what java excels at.

Comment: I develop in java, but I think it's better to develop each piece of code independently, when possible.

Comment: I listen about mocking before. That (with TDD) might also be what I am looking for.

Comment: I fear my question is not well-put. I take any reformulation advice :-).

Answer (score 3):

Definitely take a look at [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-introducing-spring-boot). Relatively new project. Its aim is to remove initial configuration phase and spin up Spring apps quickly. You can think about it as convention over configuration wrapper on top of Spring Framework.

It's also considered as good fit for micro-services architecture.

It has embedded servlet container (Jetty/Tomcat), so you don't need to configure it.
It also has various different bulk dependencies for different technology combinations/stacks. So you can pick good fit for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

What does "develop and run independent code in this context" mean?

Do you mean "small standalone example code snippets?"

- Use the Maven exec plugin
- Write unit/integration tests
- Bring your Maven dependencies into something like a JRuby REPL

Comment: I don't really understand your answer. What should I do to develop code snippets? How should I use Maven plugin, write --- tests and, well, I don't understand the last point but it feels out of scope/too complicated :)

Comment: @Juh_ Use the Maven exec plugin to execute those snippets with the dependency management handled by Maven. The last point is often the easiest, because getting a list of dependencies and including them on the JRuby classpath is trivial, and it allows you to do your "standalone code" in a REPL, if the point is pure exploration. If it's not exploratory, then I don't know why you'd need to write "standalone code snippets". What do the snippets *do*? What are they *for*?

Comment: So, (1) I should learn how to do the first, (2) don't know JRuby (and didn't get REPL at first), so even if it is simple, I don't feel comfortable with it. (3) I updated my question, hopefully you'll understand better my point of view: I did not see the difference between exploratory code snippets and incremental dev. Usually I start with the 1st and then, when satisfied, go to the 2nd (or else I already know how to do, and just do it)

Comment: @Juh_ Nothing will be faster than doing quick tests in the REPL. If your IDE supports Maven (they basically all do) then you can run snippets from within the IDE and skip having to know almost anything. "Incremental development" is basically TDD; it sounds more like you want TDD.